# How to read a GeoRSS in QGIS by URI?

Tags: qgis, georss, uri

If I open a GeoRSS in a Browser and save it as xml and then drag it into QGIS, I can see the live vectors.

But how can I read the same content using the URI directly?

I tried from Data Source Manager | Vector | HTTP(S) protocol, but it doesn't work: Wrong data source

OSGeo4W QGIS 3.28 win 10 PRO

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26423/can-qgis-display-georss-in-real-time

Comment: but it's a question from 11 years ago, hasn't anything changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add it, using its URL.

Try in example using https://www.comune.palermo.it/feed/rss_pm.xml

I'm using 3.28.2-Firenze for Win

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/7928